# How to solve the problem of scanning based on scanned history with Splunk?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

The requirements is to find the event_A and event_B such that

1. There is event A before it, and the event_A’s TEXT field and the
   event_B’s TEXT field have the first character identical, and the
   second characters satisfy the condition:

- the event_B’s TEXT’s 2nd character in numerical value is equal to the event_A’s corresponding
  field’s 2nd character,
- or event_B’s is 1 plus, or 1 minus of the event_A’s.

2. 

- It is after some event_A satisfying condition 1, with CATEGORY value “ALARM” and not after such event_A with CATEGORY value “CLEARED”,
- or It is after some event_A satisfying condition 1, with CATEGORY value “CLEARED”, but the event_B’s _time is within 60 minutes of the _time of event_A (CATEGORY=CLEARED)

Here are some sample data:

```
_time                           CATEGORY    TYPE    TEXT
2020-12-29T05:20:32.710-0800    ADVISORY    event_B K35JB
2020-12-29T05:37:54.462-0800    ADVISORY    event_B A05KM
2020-12-29T05:57:50.164-0800    ADVISORY    event_B K25CD
2020-12-29T05:59:06.004-0800    ALARM       event_A R20-A
2020-12-29T05:59:24.635-0800    ALARM       event_A K35-E
2020-12-29T05:59:37.200-0800    ALARM       event_A C15
2020-12-29T06:00:24.470-0800    CLEARED     event_A R20-A
2020-12-29T06:00:40.415-0800    CLEARED     event_A K35-E
2020-12-29T06:08:09.945-0800    ADVISORY    event_B R65AG
2020-12-29T06:14:24.740-0800    ADVISORY    event_B K35JB
2020-12-29T06:14:43.988-0800    ADVISORY    event_B K45JB
2020-12-29T06:56:44.642-0800    ADVISORY    event_B A77MD
2020-12-29T06:59:42.745-0800    ADVISORY    event_B C87AB
2020-12-29T07:30:39.080-0800    ADVISORY    event_B M97AF
2020-12-29T08:39:26.008-0800    ADVISORY    event_B K25BA
2020-12-29T09:46:48.175-0800    ADVISORY    event_B C25EG
```

Here is the illustration with the above sample data (with comment after # )

```
_time                           CATEGORY    TYPE    TEXT
                                                                # all the event_B without event_A before are eliminated
2020-12-29T05:59:06.004-0800    ALARM       event_A R20-A   # expecting event_B with TEXT with prefix Ri where i = 1, 2, 3
2020-12-29T05:59:24.635-0800    ALARM       event_A K35-E   # expecting event_B with TEXT with prefix Ki where i = 2, 3, 4
2020-12-29T05:59:37.200-0800    ALARM       event_A C15     # expecting event_B with TEXT with prefix Ci where i = 0, 1, 2
2020-12-29T06:00:24.470-0800    CLEARED     event_A R20-A   # only expecting event_B with TEXT with prefix Ri where i = 1, 2, 3 with _time < 2020-12-29T06:00:24.470-0800 + 60 minutes
2020-12-29T06:00:40.415-0800    CLEARED     event_A K35-E   # only expecting event_B with TEXT with prefix Ki where i = 2, 3, 4 with _time < 2020-12-29T06:00:40.415-0800 + 60 minutes
2020-12-29T06:08:09.945-0800    ADVISORY    event_B R65AG   # to be eliminated, not expected, as R6 does not match Ri, i=1, 2, 3
2020-12-29T06:14:24.740-0800    ADVISORY    event_B K35JB   # kept, as K3 matched the expected prefix, and within the time windows
2020-12-29T06:14:43.988-0800    ADVISORY    event_B K45JB   # kept, as K4 matched the expected prefix, and within the time windows
2020-12-29T06:56:44.642-0800    ADVISORY    event_B A77MD   # to be eliminated, not expected, as A7 does not match any of the expected prefix
2020-12-29T06:59:42.745-0800    ADVISORY    event_B C87AB   # to be eliminated, not expected, as C8 does not match Ci, i=0, 1, 2
2020-12-29T07:30:39.080-0800    ADVISORY    event_B M97AF   # to be eliminated, not expected, as M9 does not match any of the expected prefix
2020-12-29T08:39:26.008-0800    ADVISORY    event_B K25BA   # to be eliminated, not expected, as its _time is beyond the expected window
2020-12-29T09:46:48.175-0800    ADVISORY    event_B C25EG   # kept, as C2 matched the expected prefix, and there is no time window limit for the prefx C2
```

I cannot wrap my head to figure a solution with Splunk query.

I could only find a solution when there is only one event_A expecting the corresponding event_B, using streamstats to keep of track the only one expecting event_A’s TEXT prefix, and _time to scan for the satisfying event_B, but once there are multiple event_A’s expecting with different TEXT prefixes and _time’s, then I cannot find a way to remember and perform the scan for the multiple event_A’s expectations.

With a conventional programming language, say Python, I’ll keep track of the union of expecatant prefixes, and time windows, and scan the events against such history state.

Could you kindly help me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there any *other* linking data in your events? A hostname, ip address, etc?